# Customary Functions Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a game for a homework assignment, and it tours around the school. I have relatively good python coding skills. This question is more of a how-to than a why question.

So the question is how do you make a function that changes depending on what class it's in. Here is an example.

```py
def location_screen(): 

  if location_type == 'What ever': 
     print ('''
This is location type what ever''') 

  elif location_type == 'This is a nifty location': 
     print ('''
This is location type what ever''')
```

Now I want the results to be inside the class which tells the function its location type. Example:

```
class Schoolgates(): 

  location_type = "This is a nifty location" 
  location_screen()
```

So, it doesn't seem to be defining the location type. Please bare in mind I am trying to use the least amount of lines of code as possible.

Comment: Why not pass the function what it needs to do its job? Using nonlocal variables for implicit inputs is not very clean coding. In any event, what you are trying to do is being thwarted by Python's lexical scoping rules. There are workarounds, but refactoring the code is preferable.

Comment: I'm assuming the location_screen function is not defined within the class?

if so you could just pass a string directly to it
`class Schoolgates:
    location_message = "print this"
    location_screen(location_message)`

Then in location_screen just print the parameter directly instead of checking the type

You could also define the function as part of the class instead so it would take a self argument
`def location_screen(self):
    print(self.location_message)`
it would allow you to directly access attributes defined in the class (or instances of the class)

Comment: What do you mean by "what class [the function] is in"? If the function is a member of the relevant classes, you can just use `self.location_type`?

Comment: What I mean is, there are a couple of different types of locations e.g (classrooms, hallways, etcetera)  I want it so that when you enter a classroom, no matter what classroom, it shows up the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you are referencing `location_type`, you must keep in mind your [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Function_scope). When you call the function inside the class, that function does not have access to the scope of the class since it is defined outside of the class.

Also, I would recommend running the function `location_screen` after in `__init__` to be sure that you have `location_type` first. Additionally, use `self` to be more specific in your scope. The code would look something like what follows:

```py
class Schoolgates(): 
  def __init__(self):
    # set the location type for this instance of the object
    self.location_type = "This is a nifty location"

    # call the method based on this instance of the object
    self.location_screen()

  def location_screen(self): 

    if self.location_type == 'What ever': 
       print ('''
This is location type what ever''') 

    elif self.location_type == 'This is a nifty location': 
       print ('''
This is location type what ever''')
```

Of course you can still set the variable like you did above if the method is defined within the `Schoolgates` Class, however using `self` makes which variable you are referencing less ambiguous.